# How to render HTML inside Text Area in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting template contents in HTML and I want to display them in rendered form like proper styled text inside Text Area in view.

JS:

```
inviteMessage = "<p>Hello,<br />Name: asdasdasda<br />State Code: 18lc81<br /><br />For accessing site <a href="example.com">click here</a>:<br />example.com</p>";
$scope.inviteMsg = $sce.trustAsHtml(inviteMessage);
```

View:

```
<textarea rows="12" id="inviteMsg" name="inviteMsg" ng-model="inviteMsg"
                              class="form-control field" ng-bind-html="inviteMsg"></textarea>
```

Currently, its showing html with all its tags inside text area.

Comment: it mean that there is problem with Angularjs code

Comment: @Arpit is it possible to parse HTML in js side?

Comment: @pirabdulwakeel it doesn't work. It returns the same result.

Comment: can you please create a fiddle ?

Comment: yes you can but it's not good practice because purpose of angularjs is not rendering html on javascript

Comment: @Arpit I know but I am stuck. Secondly, if I am binding ng-bind-html on a div, it works perfectly but as soon as I apply it on textarea. it messes up

Comment: please jsfiddle it then only we can fix your problem

Comment: ok, let me create it.

Comment: Well to say this it short, you can't render HTML in a TEXTAREA, only TEXT. It's not an Angular restriction ... it's just how textarea works in HTML. Are you looking to display a piece of html, render it and be able to maybe move things around and edit it?

Comment: @CAT yep, I am populating Text Area with default text and this text can be editable. But I am getting default text in HTML form.

Comment: Unfortunelly I'm not sure what you need. Create a really simple fiddle with a textarea and what you have in it and explain what you expected to be.

Comment: Are you looking for something like ckeditor or medium? Basically bold a text and you want it to show bolded in the textarea?